# Is Apache Spark justified to process 100k events every 30 minutes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been evaluating Apache Spark as the processing engine for the ad-tech platform at [DeltaX](http://www.deltax.com). Everything seems to be good - but I am not sure if we fall into the Big Data category yet.

We are currently processing about 5 million events a day (~10GB) through our tracking system. We want to process the on-going data every 30 minutes - that is an average of 100k events every 30 minutes. We are expecting a 5x growth in the volume in the near future.

Architecturally, I see this is a good fit for a distributed processing system like Apache Spark. 
I also feel that streaming (spark streaming) feels natural to kind of data that we have - click streams, view streams and other advertising related events that are coming in to our tracking system.

Does this fit the use case for Apache Spark ? 
Or is Spark (and other related Big Data technologies) justifiable (and viable) only beyond a certain threshold? (yes, the 3V principle - Volume, Variety, Velocity)

PS - I used AWS EMR. 1 master, 4 core nodes (r4.2xlarge - 8 cores / 60GB RAM each node)

Comment: This isn't a good question for stack overflow, as it is more of a high level IT management question and not a programming question.  Also the decision to use spark and on Amazon or not involves a number of tradeoffs, for which we don't have the information.  For instance, do you have to hire or train programmers? Who will maintain it? What if it breaks? Does it need to survive a regional outage?  etc...

Comment: Hi Paul, I understand that this isn't particularly a programming question - but I do not think this is an IT management question either. 

I am simply trying to understand if Apache Spark is a good fit in our data processing pipeline.

I am a full stack developer and I wrote the processing code - so this isn't about programmers either.

Yes - as you mentioned, there are a number of tradeoffs. Picking AWS as a cloud provider is one of them - I like the managed Apache Spark offering without having to worry about infrastructure.

Comment: So to clarify my question again - I am looking for an opinion on whether Apache Spark is a right fit for this volume of data (100k events every 30 minutes).

Comment: "looking for an opinion" = There's a reason to close questions as "primary opinion based". I don't know if Spark is all you'd be interested in. For example, Kafka would yield good event data throughput

Comment: If you wrote the code, and you have a spark cluster configured, then you can performance test it and see it if will handle the number of events in question.  You could, for instance, run old events through it as if they all came in during a 30 minute window and see how many it will process.  You may get more out of it after some tuning or setting it up yourself or with the script that comes with spark, as Amazon makes more money when you rent more machines, not fewer.  Also, python is about an order of magnitude slower than scala for CPU-bound tasks.